# How many queues does the linux scheduler use?

Tags: linux, multithreading

Given the following

1. `SCHED_OTHER` scheduling policy for all threads
2. All threads are non realtime (`sched_priority` is 0)
3. `CONFIG_FAIR_GROUP_SCHED` is enabled
4. autogrouping is enabled.
5. There are two linux sessions each constituting a process group.

**Scenario 1**: CPU affinities are not set so all threads across both process groups fight over the same cores. Processes in both process groups are single threaded.

This is my understanding of how the linux scheduler will deal with scenario 1:
Threads that are in the same process group will be put in the same task group. Since linux is a CFS scheduler it will ensure that both process groups get roughly equal time on the common cores. The nice value will ONLY affect scheduling order within the same task group. The scheduling order within a task group is determined by the nice value and how much time the thread has spent away from the cores.

Question 1: Does linux maintain a red black tree for every task group? so in this case it will have 2?

Question 2: Since the nice value does not affect scheduling order across a task group then is there a separate queue to determine which task group's red black tree to traverse to get the next thread to be scheduled from?

Question 3: Is it possible to set an inter process group nice value type parameter that will make sure that most of the time one process group is prioritized over another?

**Scenario 2**: Same as scenario 1 but now all the processes are multithreaded.

Question 4: If the processes are multithreaded then does the linux scheduler maintain another priority queue per process (on top of the one for the processes within a process group) for finding the order of scheduling the threads spawned by a particular process (inter thread scheduling order for every process)? or will all the threads spawned by processes within the same process group get treated like independent tasks and added to the priority queue for the task group?

**Scenario 3**: Same as scenario 2 but now every single process gets a non overlapping cpu affinity.

Question 5: In this case how do the task groups that were created for every process group make sense anymore? Now threads within every process fight over cpus but threads across processes and across process groups do not fight over cores anymore. How does the CFS scheduler modify task groups? It does not make sense to have a red black tree for a process group anymore.

Question 6: Does each logical cpu get its own queue independent of the scheduler?

I would expect it to have a priority queue that determines the order of each task group (process group), and another priority queue to determine the order of tasks (processes) within a task group and a final priority queue for threads within a task (process).

Not sure how the task groups change with cpu affinities.

Comment: Threads in Linux started out as a specialized kind of entry in the process table, and they have evolved from there. The logical end point of that evolution is a state where threads are the only thing that is scheduled, and processes are mere containers for the privileges, virtual memory, open file handles,... associated with a set of one or more threads. I'm not going to try to answer your question though, because I have no idea how far Linux has come along that evolutionary path.

Comment: @SolomonSlow that makes sense and kind of what I expected. But the most confusing thing is my question about task groups and cpu affinities. A red black tree does not make sense when you have non overlapping affinities because there is no longer competition for the same cores